# Performance issue when adding classes to large DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a very large group of `divs` (over 5000) which I need to apply a `class` to. This operation causes a significant performance drain / UI lag.

I've tried two methods to add the `class` to the `divs`:

```
// jQuery approach
$("div", "#document").addClass("default");

// Vanilla JS (HTML5)
var obj_list = document.getElementById("document").querySelectorAll('div');

for (var index = 0; index < obj_list.length; index++) 
{
    obj_list[index].classList.add("action"); 
}
```

Neither method provide any noticeable difference performance wise. I'm wondering if there's another option for achieving this?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just add a class to the container instead?

Comment: Why adding the same class to all div? Why not add the class to the body and have a style .class div{ .. }

Comment: I was simplifying my question from the reality of my situation. There are other divs with different class names. I essence, I'm applying the default class to all divs which don't have a class already applied to them by earlier code.

Comment: Without your actual problem code it's pretty much impossible to help you unless people just go on wild guesses about stuff and try to come up with things that may or may not help you.

Comment: I think you can do It asynchronously without blocking your browser. See my answer below.

Comment: Just get creative with your css, no need to add more classes https://jsfiddle.net/5wwg1q5j/63/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to do some experiments with huge count of `<div>` elements in one page.

Here It is my example:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .default {

        color: red;
    }
</style>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

    $('#generate').click(function() {

        for (var i = 0; i <= 5000; i++) {

            $('#container').append('<div class="tick">some text</div>');
        }
    });

    $('#add').click(function() {

        var
            divs,
            countFrom,
            length,
            runner,
            requestAnimation;

        divs = document.getElementById("container").querySelectorAll('div');
        countFrom = 0;
        length = divs.length;

        runner = function() {

            if (countFrom < length) {

                divs[countFrom++].className = 'default'; 
                requestAnimationFrame(runner)
            }
            else {

                cancelAnimationFrame(requestAnimation);
                console.log('READY');
            }
        };

        requestAnimation = requestAnimationFrame(runner);
    });
});
</script>
<div>
    <input type="button" id="generate" value="Generate"> <br>
    <input type="button" id="add" value="Run it! Yay!"> <br>
</div>
<div id="container">

</div>
```

First click on "**Generate**" button (5000 divs will be appended to container). Next click "**Run It**" button. The process will be started asynchronously. The page will not be blocked by the process.

To run this process asynchronously, I have used [Window.requestAnimationFrame()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) method instead of slow setInterval().

Script speed: one **addClass** operation per frame. You can easily increase this speed by modifying my code. For example, 100 **addClass** operations per frame by using for loop...

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/logual/rzzhx6gv/)

Comment: Hmm... very interesting. I was unfamiliar with requestAnimationFrame. Must look into it more, but it seems like the way to go. Could you also include sample code for a loop for 100 addClass operations per frame?